# How can I lock my screen and keep my youtube playlist going?

Tags: lock-screen, youtube

How can I lock my screen and keep my youtube playlist going?

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+L doesn't work for you? you should include more information as if what you have tried already or etc...

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+L nor Super+L work for me, and my version of ubuntu (12.04? the stable one) doesn't have the lock option you see below, just suspend i think (though it does have light locker).

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? Is it official Ubuntu distro downloaded e.g. at ubuntu.com? That's weird because I used to run Ubuntu 12.04LTS Standard Unity before and it had locker indeed just pressing Ctrl+Alt+L always locked it.

Comment: Well, i got a USB version somewhere and it updates regularly. Terminal sez i have                                                                                                   Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver`, and then `gnome-screensaver-command -l` to lock your screen but keep processes running. Or, run `sleep 1 && xset dpms force off` to sleep your screen and do the same.  You can set them as a shortcut on "Keyboard". YES!

Answer (score 1):

While playing the video, press <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You can play the song from youtube and then lock the screen by

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Alternatively you can lock from menu:

[image: Lock screen]

Comment: I don't have a key marked `Super` on my keyboard. What's an alternative?

Comment: Super is the key with Windows logo on it. It is next to the right Ctrl

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+L nor Super+L work for me, and my version of ubuntu (12.04? the stable one) doesn't have the lock option you see below, just suspend i think (though it does have light locker). –